# How do I replace multiple items in a list?

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, character

I have added several characters in a list to replace in a string. Here they are:

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add(',');
list.add('?');
list.add(',');
list.add(':');
list.add('-');
list.add('(');
list.add(')');
list.add(';');
list.add('/');
```

I want to replace all occurrences of the character in the list in a string "s".

```
s.replaceAll(list, "");
```

I can't do that, of course, because list is NOT a string. But what can I do instead?

EDIT so if

```
String s = "I am cool; not good!";
```

I want the list to recognize that it contains ";" and "!", and replace those characters in the String s with nothing. So the result would be:

```
"I am cool not good"
```

Comment: You can't look for Strings in the list since it holds only Characters. Do you mean to remove all 's' Characters from the list? Or when you say replace it, replace with *what*?

Comment: I want to replace all those characters in the list with "" in the string.

Comment: Rather than a List why not use a regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than use a `List<Character>`, I would use a regex:

```
s.replaceAll("[,?:();/-]","");
```

If you absolutely must define your characters in a List, convert the List to such a regex first.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than  List why not use a regular expression. Otherwise you may be stuck with something like:

```
StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder(myString);
for (Character myChar : list) {
  mySB.replace(String.valueOf(myChar), "");
}

myString = mySB.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

check out Apache Commons [StringUtils.replaceEach((String text,
                                 String[] searchList,
                                 String[] replacementList))](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) it will allow you to provide a list of values to search for and a list of associated replacements in a single line.

**Note**: This will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if the lengths of the search and replacement arrays are not the same